# How to get a YouTube video's duration/length using Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to extract the title, duration and the link of all the videos that a YT channel has. I used selenium and python in the following way:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

results = []

url = "https://www.youtube.com/channel/<channel name>/videos"

driver.get(url)

ht=driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight;")
while True:
    prev_ht=driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight;")
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.documentElement.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(2)
    ht=driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight;")
    if prev_ht==ht:
        break

links=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="style-scope ytd-grid-renderer"]')
for link in links:
    print()
    print(link.get_attribute("href"), link.get_attribute("text"))
```

When I try to get the duration of the video using  `class="style-scope ytd-thumbnail-overlay-time-status-renderer"` class, the driver returns that the element doesn't exist. I managed the got the other two features though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath locator is not correct, so please use the following:

```
links=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[name() = "ytd-grid-video-renderer" and @class="style-scope ytd-grid-renderer"]')
```

Now, to get the videos length per each link you defined you can do the following:

```
links=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[name() = "ytd-grid-video-renderer" and @class="style-scope ytd-grid-renderer"]')
for link in links:
    duration = link.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[contains(@class,"time-status")]').text
    print(duration)
```

Comment: Not working though, selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//span[contains(@class,'time-status')]"}
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.212)

Comment: Does your list of web elements `links` containing a list of web elements? I saw there 60 elements on my side.

Comment: I saw again and found that your locator was not correct. Please see the updated answer and let me know if now it works correct

Comment: Yes, I have not used selenium that much, but your last update got it working fine.

Comment: Great! I'm happy we did this!

Answer (score 0):

Good Morning!

Selenium can have trouble getting the video duration if the cursor is not in the perfect spot. Here's a GIF to show that: [Gif](https://i.imgur.com/bmWdC7A.gif). You can get around this by using some of Youtube's built-in Javascript functions. Here's an example that uses this:

```
video_dur = self.driver.execute_script(
                    "return document.getElementById('movie_player').getCurrentTime()")

video_len = self.driver.execute_script(
                    "return document.getElementById('movie_player').getDuration()")

video_len = int(video_len) / 60
```

Have a great day!